# In AutoIt, WinWait still waits after the window has opened

Tags: loops, window, autoit

I used AU3info to make sure I am using the right windows title.

```
RunWait ("\\sv44\vol1\Install\LibreOffice\install /exenoui")
WinWait("Installation of LibreOffice")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

What I am trying to achieve: When I the confirmation box appears ("Installation of LibreOffice"), press <kbd>OK</kbd>.

WinWait loops forever. I tried WinWaitActive...same result.

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

When manipulating external application windows, always use #RequireAdmin in order to get a permission elevation. Also use Opt("WinSearchChildren", 1) in order to search child windows too. Play with "WinTitleMatchMode".

```
#RequireAdmin ; Will give your script a permission elevation (sometimes its needed)
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2) ; 1=start, 2=subStr, 3=exact, 4=advanced, -1 to -4=Nocase
Opt("WinSearchChildren", 1) ; 0=no, 1=search children also

RunWait("\\sv44\vol1\Install\LibreOffice\install /exenoui")
WinWait("Installation of LibreOffic")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Notice that I use "Installation of LibreOffic" (missing "e") because Opt is set to use substring and not the whole title (just in case).